# How to send email in php with jquery validation

Tags: php, jquery, email

I just started learning the basics of php and am wanting to understand the content from w3schools classes.

My html looks like this:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" id="main-contact-form">
<br style="clear:both">
    <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Contact a Conveyancing Property Lawyer Now</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="140" rows="7" name="message"></textarea>
        <span class="help-block"><p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">You have reached the limit</p></span>                    
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Then my jquery file looks like this:

```
$('#main-contact-form').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'sendememail.php',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    success:function(response){ 
        if(response==1)
        {   

            setInterval(function(){$('.review_form').html('<h5><center><div class="alert alert-success">Review Successfully Submitted......</div></center></h5>');},5);

        }
        else 
        {

            setInterval(function(){$('.review_form').html('<h5><center><div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry Your Review Was Not Submitted......</div></center></h5>');},5);

        }
    }

   });
  });
```

From what I could see, this is how more or less how an email is sent:

```
<?php
    $to = "sidney@web2web.co.za";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $txt = "Hello world!";
    $headers = "sidney@web2web.co.za" . "\r\n" .
    "CC: personal@website.com";

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

My sendemail.php looks like this:

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
$to = $email;
$subject = $subject;
$txt = $message;
$headers = "sidney@web2web.co.za" . "\r\n" .
"CC: personal@website.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

When I click on submit button, I get the error that you can see in the image:

[image]

Hope you can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To send data from form to php without refreshing page you need to use AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Create new page for send email like sendemail.php and input your email code in it.

Remove action from form and add attribute id in form tag.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" id="main-contact-form">
<br style="clear:both">
        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Contact a Conveyancing Property Lawyer Now</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="140" rows="7" name="message"></textarea>
            <span class="help-block"><p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">You have reached the limit</p></span>                    
        </div>

        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Then change your JQuery shown below:

```
<script>
$('#main-contact-form').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'sendememail.php',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    success:function(response){ 
        if(response==1)
        {   

            setInterval(function(){$('.review_form').html('<h5><center><div class="alert alert-success">Review Successfully Submitted......</div></center></h5>');},5);

        }
        else 
        {

            setInterval(function(){$('.review_form').html('<h5><center><div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry Your Review Was Not Submitted......</div></center></h5>');},5);

        }
    }

   });
  });
 </script>
```

Here Your sendemail.php :

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
$to = $email;
$subject = $subject;
$txt = $message;
$headers = "sidney@web2web.co.za" . "\r\n" .
"CC: personal@website.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Email is send you entered in email textbox.

Comment: but how exactly do I if I want the email to be sent to me. Say my email is user@gmail.com. How would my php look like?

Comment: see my edit code.